# Optional columns in SQL Server insert statement based on input values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that with an insert statement for a table in SQL Server 2012.

It lists all columns and the values as such:

```
insert into TABLE_NAME (name, rating, link) 
values (@name, @rating, @link).
```

The problem I have is that some of the columns are specified as null but the values passed to the stored procedure as empty strings (or zero for int column types that allow nulls) and I do not want to insert an empty string or a zero in a column that allows nulls.

Is there a way to modify the insert statement to exclude those columns whose values should not be inserted, based only on the values of the parameters passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exclude the values from the insert statement dynamically, but you can use [the `NULLIF` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to convert your input values to `NULL` if they're empty string or whatever you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (name, rating, link) 
SELECT NULLIF(@name, ''), NULLIF(@rating, 0), NULLIF(@link, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that SQL Server allows an expression with "DEFAULT", where you could say:

```
insert into TABLE_NAME (name, rating, link)
    values (coalesce(@name, default), coalesce(@rating, default), coalesce(@link, default))
```

So, that leaves dynamic SQL.  Something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'insert into TABLE_NAME(name, rating, link)
                 values (' + (case when @name is null then 'default' else '@name' end) + ', ' +
                         (case when @rating is null then 'default' else '@rating' end) + ', ' +
                         (case when @link is null then 'default' else '@link' end))';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@name ??, @rating ??, @link ??',
      @name = @name, @rating = @rating, @link = @link;
```